# Create a Table(s) with Users and Groups

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

I'm building a rental application for school. There will be three groups will have access to this application. Managers, Associates and Owner. Each group may have restrictions on the functionality. My issue is that I created a login form and I need to redirect the user(according to their group) to another form. I need to create a table with users and groups to be able to cal a certain group when the user enters their Username and Password.

I've tried to create a table, but then I got stuck on which data should I  put as a foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
                UserID INT NOT NULL,
                PASSWORD VARCHAR(50),
                PRIMARY KEY(UserID)
                );

CREATE TABLE Groups (
                    GroupID INT,
                    GroupName VARCHAR,
                    PRIMARY KEY(GroupID)
                    );

CREATE TABLE User_Groups (
                        UserID INT,
                        GroupID INT,
                        );
```

Comment: For which table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a user belongs exactly to one group, and it looks like this is the case here, you better put the group ID in the user table. Constraint it as a foreign key to the ID in the groups table, to be sure only valid group IDs can be inserted, and as not null, to enforce that it has to be set.

```
CREATE TABLE groups
             (grouid integer,
              groupname varchar(50),
              PRIMARY KEY (groupid));

CREATE TABLE users
             (userid integer,
              username varchar(50),
              password varchar(50),
              grouid integer NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (userid),
              FOREIGN KEY (groupid)
                          REFERENCES groups
                                     (groupid));
```